# How to apply an IN clause in Perl by passing arguments from the command line

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am new to Perl, and am trying to apply a filter condition on XML files using the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) module.

Following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $SOURCEFILE     = $ARGV[0];
my $FILELOCATIONIN = $ARGV[1];

my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { 'STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&STOCK } );

$twig->parsefile($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'.xml');

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');

$twig->print_to_file($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'out.xml');

sub TRADE {
    my ( $twig, $STOCK ) = @_;
    foreach  my $c ($STOCK)
        {
         $c->delete($STOCK)
         unless
         $c->att('origin') eq "HIGH_TRADE"

      ;
    }
}
```

Following is my XML :

```
<STOCKEXT>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "LOW_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "LOW_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "AVERAGE_TRADE"/>
</STOCKEXT>
```

Filtered Output XML:

```
<STOCKEXT>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin = "HIGH_TRADE"/>
</STOCKEXT>
```

Now I am stuck, as I want to pass comma-separated argument in the command line so that `HIGH_TRADE` as well as `AVERAGE_TRADE` become legitimate `STOCK`.

As can be seen, in my current code, I pass two arguments. But I want to pass three arguments, third should be the filter condition in comma-separated format.

Hence, I am expecting my code to be invoked as

```
perl stock_filter.pl file_name.xml /opt/XML HIGH_TRADE,AVERAGE_TRADE
```

The third argument will be split and checked against the `origin` attribute of each `STOCK` element to declare it as legitimate.

This will help in future to change the filter conditions. Any addition or subtraction of filter condition will not change the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to store the values that you want to keep in a hash.

Create the hash at the top of the script:

```
my @origins_to_keep= split /,/, $ARGV[2];
my %keep= map { $_ => 1 } @origins_to_keep;
```

Use it in the handler:

```
$c->delete($STOCK) unless $keep{$c->att('origin')}
```

Comment: Global symbol "%keep" requires explicit package name..error it's throwing...Don't understand why..

Comment: Got it ...instead of my $keep= map { $_ => 1 } origins_to_keep, it should be my %keep= map { $_ => 1 } @origins_to_keep as it's hash...thanks...

Comment: oops, fixed in the answer

Answer (score 3):

The solution most obvious to me is to use the `any` function from the [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util) module.

Here's a version of your own code that includes a few other modifications. Most significantly I've used the `catfile` function from the [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec::Functions) module to more safely combine the path and file name.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;    # For non-destructive substitution

use XML::Twig;
use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';
use List::Util 'any';

my ($source_file, $file_location, $stock_origins) = @ARGV;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => { 'STOCKEXT/STOCK' => \&stock_handler },
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
);

my $full_input    = catfile($file_location, $source_file);
my @stock_origins = split /,/, $stock_origins;
my $full_output   = $full_input =~ s/(?=\.[^.]+\z)/_out/r;

$twig->parsefile($full_input);
$twig->print_to_file($full_output);

sub stock_handler {
  my ( $twig, $stock ) = @_;
  my $origin = $stock->att('origin');

  $stock->delete unless any { $origin eq $_ } @stock_origins;
}
```

**output**

```
<STOCKEXT>
  <STOCK origin="HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin="HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin="HIGH_TRADE"/>
  <STOCK origin="AVERAGE_TRADE"/>
</STOCKEXT>
```

Comment: "any" is not exported by the List::Util module....This is error I am facing...Any idea...Sir..